# Oracle 12c - On Overflow Truncate

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, listagg

My database has been upgraded to Oracle 12c. I want to convert some of my queries to use "on overflow truncate" but I get "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error.

I double-checked that the upgrade did go to 12c with this command and it does show the database as 12c:
**select * from v$version**

Being new to using "on overflow truncate" I built the simplest query I could come up with just to learn how to use this command and I get the same error. Here is my simple query:
**select listagg(myfield, ';' on overflow truncate) within group (order by myfield) from mytable**

Also, I had initially tried this command and I get "ORA-01489:result of string concatenation too long", which is what I want because I want to play with this new command's options to see how they look (yes, I purposely left off the criteria to make this get big):
**select listagg(myfield, ';') within group (order by myfield) from mytable**

Can anyone give me an idea in what way I'm misunderstanding how to use "on overflow truncate"?

Comment: Which specific version of "12c" do you have though? Note that the "c" is just a marketing tag; the proper way to refer to your version is 12.1 or 12.2, and sometimes the subversion (as in , 12.1.0.1.0) is relevant too. In this case: the ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE option was added in 12.2, it did not exist in 12.1. `V$VERSION` will show your full version number.

Comment: Here is all of what I get because I also wondered if my PL/SQL version might be causing an issue (is that a possibility?):                             
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: From your response, mathguy, I do see that our version would not have this feature. So, that is the issue and I thank you for your help on this.